# Fruit-bearing tree identification

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

Just moved into a new house in Puerto Rico and I found this tree in the back garden. Can anyone tell me what tree this is, and whether its fruit is edible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Telling us where on Earth you're located would be helpful...

Comment: It is in Puerto Rico.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a [Canistel (Pouteria campechiana)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pouteria_campechiana):

[image]

The fruit are yellow when when ripe, but the form and also the leaves look very similar. The fruit are edible raw, you can find some more information [here](http://www.fruitsinfo.com/Canistel-fruit.php).

Comment: +1, but OP also asks if its fruit is edible?